# notepad++ udl for log4net how to highlight the rest of line after the word that contains key word

Tags: notepad++, log4net

I want to highlight the rest of a line after the word "Exception:".
but there are more than one exception...

for example:
"IOException:"
"UnauthorizedAccessException:"
"FileNotFoundException:"

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to highlight part of a string inside Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Find and mark in the search mode Regular Expression. Now you need to write a Regular Expression that match any line with `Exception`. This is something you can do your self with some help of google.